# How to remove duplicate tags from grouped options select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have 2 grouped options with a duplicate tag.

[image]

When selected, the tags appears twice, from each group.

How to avoid this duplicate entry ?

I have prepared a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/PBrockmann/cvg4h98b/

```
var tagsCat1 = [
  "AAA",
  "BBB",
  "CCC"
];

var childrenCat1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tagsCat1.length; i++) {
  childrenCat1.push({
    id: tagsCat1[i],
    text: tagsCat1[i]
  });
}

var tagsCat2 = [
  "DDD",
  "EEE",
  "BBB" // duplicate tag 
];

var childrenCat2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tagsCat2.length; i++) {
  childrenCat2.push({
    id: tagsCat2[i],
    text: tagsCat2[i]
  });
}

var options = [];
options.push({
  text: "Cat1",
  children: childrenCat1
});
options.push({
  text: "Cat2",
  children: childrenCat2
});

$('#example1').select2({
  data: options,
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'select...',
});
```

Select tag "BBB". It will be displayed 2 times.

Comment: you can perhaps make the id unique such that even when the text is same the id is unique. for example by appending Cat1 infront if it belongs to cat 1 something like `childrenCat1.push({ id: "Cat1-"+tagsCat1[i], text: tagsCat1[i] })`

Comment: Indeed... Thanks

Comment: would you like to post as an answer

Comment: Done. Please vote for it.

Comment: btw changing the `text` is not compulsory for it work but i guess u know it already

Comment: Yes indeed.. Have let it for distinguish that the tag can come from 2 different groups.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to cmgchess that proposes a workaround by adding the group name before in the option.

```
var tagsCat1 = [
  "AAA",
  "BBB",
  "CCC"
];

var childrenCat1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tagsCat1.length; i++) {
  childrenCat1.push({
    id: "Cat1: " + tagsCat1[i],
    text: "Cat1: " + tagsCat1[i]   // could be just tagsCat1[i]
  });
}

var tagsCat2 = [
  "DDD",
  "EEE",
  "BBB"     // duplicate tag 
];

var childrenCat2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tagsCat2.length; i++) {
  childrenCat2.push({
    id: "Cat2: " + tagsCat2[i],
    text: "Cat2: " + tagsCat2[i]   // could be just tagsCat2[i]
  });
}

var options = [];
options.push({text: "Cat1", children: childrenCat1});
options.push({text: "Cat2", children: childrenCat2});

$('#example1').select2({
  data: options,
  tags: true,
  multiple: true,
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'select...',
});
```